# Append fields to PSQL jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table called `test_table` that has the following structure:

```
id                       | 1
lookup                   | 166
arguments                | {"title": "Title", "name": "XYZ", "address": "1 main street"}
```

I have a lot of entries into this table that follow a similar structure (I have simplified it for the purposes of this question.

I want to update certain rows (based on a list of IDs) so that there is an extra field within the arguments column that will result in this:

```
id                       | 1
lookup                   | 166
arguments                | {"title": "Title", "name": "XYZ", "address": "1 main street", "county": "County Name", "code": "4XC"}
```

I have tried the following but cannot get it to work:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET arguments = arguments || '"county": "County Name", "code": "4XC"'::jsonb
WHERE id in (1,2,etc.);
```

Can anyone advise as to what I am doing wrong?

This is the error I receive:

```
Expected end of input, but found ":"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't valid JSON, you need `{}` around it.

```
UPDATE test_table
SET arguments = arguments || '{ "county": "County Name", "code": "4XC" }'::jsonb
WHERE id in (1,2,etc.);
```

To avoid formatting problems, and to make using bind parameters easier, use `jsonb_build_object`.

```
UPDATE test_table
SET arguments = arguments || jsonb_build_object('county': ?, 'code': ?) )
WHERE id in (1,2,etc.);
```